# Why "there was a problem with vi" when saving a git commit message with :wq after accidental :Wq?

Tags: error, git

When I have typed a commit message with vim and, in haste, typed `:Wq` instead of `:wq` I get an error:

> E492: Not an editor command: Wq

from which I can (falsly?) recover, meaning the editor seems to function as normal and I can try to properly write and quit the buffer with `:wq`. However, git-commit fails with:

> error: There was a problem with the editor 'vi'.
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

What has happened? Is this a misinterpretation in git's part? Can I somehow recover and actually save the commit message after accidental `:Wq`? Besides copy and pasting what I've written…

My vi is actually symlinked to vim and version is 8.0

Comment: You can work around this issue by fixing the typo before the error occurs. A simple way to do this is with a command: `command -bang Wq wq<bang>
`. (If you ever pass arguments to `:wq` you can instead use an abbreviation: `cabbrev <expr> Wq (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 3) ? 'wq' : 'Wq'
`)

Comment: I'm not sure if your `:Wq` typo is related to the git error. As for recovering, `git commit` starts the editor on`.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`, so check the contents of that file. You can use `git commit -eF .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` to continue with that message.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker great! `COMMIT_EDITMSG` indeed does have the message I meant to use. That's how I can recover from this, thanks. Any thoughts on _why_ (or how) git interpretes vi had a problem? Technically, yes, it did have a problem and apparently the strategy is to be more safe than sorry; but where git gets "vi had a problem" status? From some metadata/variable, return state or what? I mean: is it some standard vi/vim way or just (too) fuzzy logic on git's part?

Answer (score 3):

Git actually checks the exit code of whatever editor you have configured and outputs that error message if it's non-zero.

I couldn't replicate the problem with your commands but you may have better luck. Simply run `vim` normally (i.e., *not* via `git`), enter the `:Wq` and `:wq` commands (and whatever else you did in between those two), then check the exit code with (for Linux) `echo $?`.

If that's not zero, you at least have a repeatable test you can use for further investigation, at which point you can start experimenting with `vim` options (as shown in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14497/why-would-vim-return-non-zero-exit-code-if-i-exit-immediately-after-opening) for example).

You could also opt for a different editor which *doesn't* return non-zero. There's probably no reason to need the *massive* power of Vim for composing what are (hopefully) one-liner commit messages.

In fact, I don't use *any* editor, instead relying on the command-line bevaviour only. For one-liners:

```
pax$ git commit -m "Fixed my co-worker's atrocious code :-)"
```

or, more more complex messages:

```
pax$ git commit -F - 
(reading log message from standard input)
Fixed my co-worker's atrocious code, specifically:
- no comments;
- unreadable formatting;
- bad variable names.
<CTRL-D>
```

As to how you easily get at the comment you just tried to use, that should be stored in `.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG` so you can just use:

```
git commit -F .git/COMMIT_EDITMSG
```

(or `-eF` if you want to check or further edit the message).